# how does an app signature work?

Tags: java, android, security

My questions to the code below:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
            // SHA1 the signature
            String sha1 = getSHA1(signature.toByteArray());
        }
```

If I sign the app with the same private key, but the app itself changes its content, will I get a different sha1?

My understanding what signature is:

```
Sender   : Encrypt(hash(message), priv_key) = dig_sign 
Receiver : Decrypt(dig_sign, pub_key) => hash_of_message
```

Comment: `app itself changes its content` app can't change it's content, APK file can't be changed by enything except system

Comment: ok that's a wording issue, if "the app is changed in its future version"

Comment: signature will be the same.

Comment: so if this is correct:
Encrypt(hash(message), priv_key) = dig_sign 
what is then a message in the above?

Comment: @bongo I'm not an Android expert but I would be extremely surprised if the signature would remain the same if the application content changes. Do you have a reference for that? This would mean that the content itself would not get signed, but rather some meta data or so... Just thinking out loud.

Comment: OK it seems Signature is not a real signature. See:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/Signature.html
“This class name is slightly misleading, since it's not actually a signature.“

Therefore my question is how can I perform an integrity check of an app using android.content.pm.Signature . In the current state it just contains some meta information and public key. The hash of that indeed never changes…

Comment: if anyone wants to comment the question is still open: if the code from the topic doesn't check integrity how to do it in an alternative way?

Comment: @quinz as hhg says it's not a real signature.
I'm deveopring android apps at least 6 years from now, and I am sure that signature is not changing. If signature of your app will change ( for example app is signed with other certificate ) there will be not possible to update app in play store because play store verify app signatures.